# Codeblocks undefined reference to functions error. Already tried add include directory to project build options

Tags: c, console-application, codeblocks, header-files, undefined-reference

I recently inherited a console application that I do not have the project file for. I only have the executable file, the **main.c** and a bunch of .h header files. I need to edit the main.c and produce an exe file with my edits.

- I created a new C console application project on Codeblocks then pasted the main.c contents from the "hand me down" file onto the new project's *main.c*.
- I just edited a fieldname on the main.c file. A very minor edit.
- I pasted the .h files to C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include.
- I go to Project >> Build Options >> Search directories >> Compiler >> Add the above include path (saw this step on codeblocks forum and on stackoverflow)

Now the problem is; I'm getting errors, there are multiple undefined reference to 'functionNames'.
These function names are inside the .h files.

I also included the path not just on *Compiler* but on *Linker* and *Resource compiler* to no avail, still getting the same error.

Some of the include .h on main.c also references other .h files which are also pasted on the CodeBlocks\MinGW\include folder.
The include calls are <> and not "" since they are pasted on mingw\include. These .h files are from an api package.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <global.h>
    #include <osfile.h>
    #include <mail.h>
.. etc
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: all the function definitions?

Comment: im, sorry what do you mean :((

Comment: "What am I missing? Thanks!"
the body of the functions, if you have a decleration in a header like 
void functionName();
you need the definitions of it:
void functionName()
{
 ... //the code
}

Comment: the main.c already worked before when the previous developer created the executable file. i was thinking i was just maybe missing some setting in codeblocks.

Comment: undefined references to functions means that during the compilation process the linker expects to see a body of a function somewhere in the .c files that you compiled, if there is none this error will appear, the solution is to either find and compile them with your main.c if you can get them, or define them yourself and that means writing the code for it.

Comment: It would seem that you simply didn't add the .c files to the project. In Codeblocks you can add both .h and .c files to the project just fine. Shouldn't be a need to set any manual paths unless you are doing something exotic.

Comment: ^^the body of the function are inside the .h header files. should i compile all the .h files too? ^there is only one .c in the project, and that is the main.c right? this main.c is the one that calls the other functions from the .h files.